# app should not give service call in background mode

Tags: codenameone

I have built an application  in codename one .  I want A Scenerio where if my app runs in background on device then it should not give call to the service .it should call only if user opens the application.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the developer guide for [details on background execution](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html). Generally an app can't do "anything" in the background and has a lot of restrictions when it comes to that.